# Find the CDF of W? need to verify.

Tags: probability-distributions, solution-verification, random-variables, uniform-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

[image]

My main answer for CDF is root(W)/10.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is your main answer for the CDF or PDF?

Comment: @XStanton thanks for pointing out, I've edited, CDF is main.

Comment: Thanks @angryavian for the edit.

Comment: CDF looks correct (presuming your expression is only for the interval $[0, 100]$).

Comment: @angryavian why interval [0,100]?

Comment: You meant interval for W, I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should show your working when asking people to check your work.

Your answer is correct, except you need to include the support.

$\qquad\begin{align}\mathsf P(W\leqslant w) &= \mathsf P(-\sqrt w/2\leqslant I\leqslant \sqrt w /2) \\ &= (\sqrt w /10)\,\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant \sqrt w/2\lt 5} +\mathbf 1_{5\leqslant \sqrt w/10}\\ &= (\sqrt w /10)\,\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant w\lt 100}+\mathbf 1_{100\leqslant w}\\[3ex] F_W(w) &=\begin{cases}0 &:& ~~~\qquad  w\lt 0\\\sqrt w/10&:& ~~~~0\leqslant w\lt 100\\1&:& 100\leqslant w\end{cases}\end{align}$

Comment: Thanks Graham, I will include it from now on.